# Send existing LCOV file to SonarQube

Tags: javascript, testing, sonarqube, code-coverage

Because of the way my project is built, I can't use SonarQube to run coverage on my project. I have my JavaScript coverage all working with Karma and other tools. These tools output a valid LCOV file.

Everything else I've found requires you to have SonarQube run the coverage and generate the LCOV file.

I would like to be able to just upload the LCOV file to SonarQube and have it use that. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: I was going to suggest asking SonarQube, but their [support page](http://www.sonarqube.org/get-support/) directs people to post their questions on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to understand the question, but if it is how to feed SonarQube with the LCOV report, so you just need to provide the path - absolute or relative to the project base directory - to the LCOV report via the project property "sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath". See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Plugin "Code Coverage" paragraph.

Is that answers your question ?

Comment: I believe that should work just fine. The story got pushed back, so I won't work on it for a little while, but I think this will do fine when I do. Thanks!